# Git multiple repositories in Visual Studio mark as Read Only

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2022

On VS 2022 you can manage multiple repositories.

I have a few repos on my 15 project solution that are not under my control and will like to mark them 'Read Only'.  In other words, if there is any change on the origin, will be ok to pull and merge, however I don't want (nor can) push my (temporary) changes to the origin: I just want vs/git to ignore the repository.

Comment: Where is the repo you only have read access to hosted? Most common hosting services have the feature "fork" which is meant to solve exactly this. See for example GitHub's documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo. Then you clone your fork and not the original repo.

Comment: Fork is a valid option. Some repos are on MS others on third parties. Currently I have multiple external projects and expect both number to reach over 60, most of them are temporary unloaded, I use them a reference but I usually make notes on the source code. I think that a right click on a ReadOnly' check will be a better approach. 
I know, I'm not very conventional.